# Executing a command line program in Windows 7 using something like "for each" statement

Tags: windows-7

I need to execute a program in Windows 7 that uses a file as a parameter for example:

```
foo file
```

So I need to run the program with all .txt files in a folder so the question is: Is there a way to create a bash file or maybe using the Microsoft Power Shell to do something like this:

```
for each f *.txt in c:\temp do
    foo f
```

where *f* is the file beeing preccesed?

Thank you,

Michelle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. :)

```
for %%f in (c:\temp\*.txt) do  foo %%f
```

Comment: Hi Ken, you can't split the command in two lines because it doesn't work. It works well if you write everything in one line

Comment: @Michelle, you can split it across multiple lines if you put the commands in parentheses. `for %%f in (c:\temp\*.txt) do (` on the first line, then any commands you want then `)`.

Comment: @Duncan, Thank you for your help once again :)